# SELECT BETWEEN dates not working for year - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm using this query to select data between dates:

```
SELECT id, date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '09/10/2015' and '09/23/2015';
```

I'm getting these results:

```
1   09/11/2015
2   09/13/2015
3   09/16/2015
4   09/21/2015
5   09/21/2015
6   09/21/2015
7   09/22/2015
8   09/23/2015
```

But when I change the date to one year before, instead of showing all these data again, It's returning a result ignoring the year:

```
SELECT id, date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '09/15/2014' and '09/23/2015';
```

Result:

```
3   09/16/2015
4   09/21/2015
5   09/21/2015
6   09/21/2015
7   09/22/2015
8   09/23/2015
```

What am I missing?

Edit:

Date column datatype: varchar.

Comment: Column data type? Are you comparing dates or character strings?

Comment: `date` column datatype is varchar

Comment: Since the column is varchar you are not comparing dates, you are comparing character strings. alter column to date type if possible. Or do convert to date before comparing values.

Comment: But why is It working for days and months?

Comment: Pure luck... alphabetically ordered that way.

Comment: Is the date format yyyy-mm-dd? right?
I'm gonna change the type to date... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are committing a sin . . . storing date values as strings.  This is bad.  SQL has built-in data types for dates and a wealth of functions.

So, you need to convert the data, using `str_to_date()`:

```
SELECT id, date
FROM table
WHERE str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2015-09-10' and '2015-09-23';
```

MySQL doesn't know that you intend for some string column to be a date, so all the comparisons are done as strings.  You should also get used to using the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format for representing dates.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ....

```
SELECT id, date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('09/10/2015','%d/%m/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('09/23/2015','%d/%m/%Y');
```